# ECDC/PHE covid data clash

Tags: medical, covid19

12 April's new daily confirmed cases for UK seem to be dramatically different:

- ECDC says **8719** (https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/daily-cases-covid-19?country=GBR), while
- PHE says 84279-78991=**5288** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_coronavirus_pandemic_in_the_United_Kingdom#Timeline).

Now, I know that there could be something different in the definition of "new cases" or in the way they are measured. 
What is exactly the difference due to?

Also, ECDC's data is quite alarming because it's a dramatic jump looking at ECDC's same data for the past days: should I be worried?